# SQL query for distinct most recent records with 3 or more table join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find out the best and most efficient way to do an SQL query from 3 or more tables that have a lot of records. And I need to get the most recent distinct ones.

Here is an example of the model:

[DB Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWLft.png)

I need the SQL to return something like:

```
1  JON     Description 2   01/Dez/2024     Microsoft
3  Alfred  Description 3   01/Jan/2023     IOS
```

I need to retrieve the distinct Jon record that has the most recent project start date and Alfred that is the only record for that employee.

Can you help?

I've already tried a bunch of SQL queries and I'm not getting the results I need as something is always repeating Jons records.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Instead of images of your tables you should post the create table statements followed by insert statements for sample data. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.)

Comment: "I'm trying to find out the best and most efficient way" - do you have a working query that is inefficient?

Comment: We really need a [mre] with both sample data and desired results (as tabular markdown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script uses CTE's to first identify the latest date per user, then the latest ProjectId where multiple projects have the same latest StartDate (assuming a greater Project.ID means it was created later)

- **LatestDate**: Identifies the latest StartDate per employee.
- **LatestProject**: Identifies the latest ProjectId if multiple use the same LatestDate.

```
    WITH LatestDate AS (
    SELECT           EmployeeId              
                    ,MAX(StartDate) AS MaxDate
    FROM             Project
    GROUP BY         EmployeeId
    )
    
    ,LatestProject AS (
    SELECT           L.EmployeeId
                    ,L.MaxDate AS StartDate
                    ,MAX(P.ID) AS LatestProjectId
    FROM             LatestDate AS L
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  Project AS P ON P.EmployeeId=L.EmployeeId 
    AND              P.StartDate=L.MaxDate
    GROUP BY         L.EmployeeId
                    ,L.MaxDate
    )
    
    SELECT           E.EmployeeId
                    ,E.Name
                    ,P.Description
                    ,P.StartDate
                    ,C.Name
    FROM             Employee AS E
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  LatestProject AS L ON L.EmployeeId=E.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  Project AS P ON P.ID=L.LatestProjectId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  Company AS C ON C.ID=E.CompanyId
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
Ranking each project by user ordered by start date desc and keeping the most recent one i.e. the one with rank = 1

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT e.id
         , e.name
         , p.description
         , p.start_date
         , c.name
         , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.id ORDER BY p.start_date DESC) AS "RANK"
    FROM employee e
    INNER JOIN project p ON e.id = p.employee_id
    INNER JOIN company c ON c.id = e.company_id
) 
WHERE rank = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 

* -- extract what you need

from employee E
join project P on P.EmployeeId = E.id
join

(select EmployeeId,MAX(StardDate) as MaxStartDate
from project
group by EmployeeId) T on T.EmployeeId = P.EmployeeId and T.MaxStartDate=P.StartDate

join company c on c.id = E.CompanyId
```

Comment: PS. you would most likely need to add an index too.
CREATE INDEX idx_employee_startdate ON project (EmployeeId, StartDate);

Comment: I've tried this one and it worked good, but if I had two equal dates it would give me duplicates. So I went with the other solution posted by @Graeme LM

Comment: what should be the requirement? just picking a random one or picking the one with the highest project id? that should have been specified in the question tho